# How can i create a high priority thread than main thread in QT

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have set a main thread prority to **NormalPriority(3)**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QThread::currentThread()->setPriority(QThread::NormalPriority);
    qDebug()<<"Main Priority="<< QThread::currentThread()->priority();
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

and i have created another thread from MainWindow.cpp

```
MyThread MyThreadObj;
MyThreadObj.start(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);
```

after this, i have print the priority values

```
qDebug()<<"MainWindow Priority="<< MainWindow::thread()->priority();
qDebug()<<"MyThread Priority="<< MyThreadObj->thread()->priority();
```

Output is

```
Main Priority=3
MainWindow Priority=6
MyThread Priority=6
```

How can i create a high priority thread than main thread?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. The output is as expected, given your code. `MainWindow::thread()->priority()` is useless, since a window must always be in the GUI (main thread). This line simply means "return the priority of the thread of `this`. You seem to be running that line in an object that's owned by the thread, obviously after doing the **wrong thing**, namely `MyThreadObj->moveToThread(MyThreadObj)`. Don't do that.

Comment: i have changed the second thread priority only. But also change the main thread priority

Comment: No, it doesn't. The line that prints out the first `6` doesn't do what you think it does. Both lines that print `6` refer to the same thread - just print out the value of the `thread()` that you access and you will see that. You wrote perfectly obfuscated C++ that does not what one might casually think it would.

Comment: Add `Q_ASSERT(MainWindow::thread() == MyThreadObj->thread())` - you'll see that the assert succeeds! That's because this line is equivalent to `Q_ASSERT(this->thread() == MyThreadObj->thread())`, and you are *demonstrably* calling it from inside the thread's `run()` method!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is. The output is as expected, given your code.

`MainWindow::thread()->priority()` is useless, since a window must always be in the GUI (main thread). Besides, this line doesn't even do what you think it does. It's equivalent to calling `QObject::thread()->priority()`, further equivalent to `this->thread()->priority()`. It simply means "return the priority of the thread of this. You seem to be running that line in an object that's owned by the thread, obviously after doing the wrong thing, namely `MyThreadObj->moveToThread(MyThreadObj)`. Don't do that.

The below works hopefully to your expectations. Note the abject absence of `myThread->moveToThread`. It's not needed. If you need to emit signals from a `QThread`, use a helper object that lives in that thread. Or, perhaps, just use a plain `QObject` that is moved to the thread.

```
MyThread Priority=6
Main Priority=3
MainWindow Priority=3
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread myThread;
    myThread.start(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);
    qDebug()<<"MyThread Priority="<< myThread.priority();

    Q_ASSERT_X(myThreadObj.thread() == QThread::currentThread(),
               "myThreadObj", "Usually moving a QThread to another thread is an error");

    qDebug()<<"Main Priority="<< QThread::currentThread()->priority();

    QMainWindow w;
    qDebug()<<"MainWindow Priority="<< w.thread()->priority();

    myThread.quit();
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can give priority to child thread.

[Qt thread priority](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#setPriority)